# PHP num_returns always returns 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**EDIT: Solved**

I've found the solution I was looking for. Thanks to Alex for pointing out my mistake.

I was trying to count the number of results from the query that are not empty.

Here's how I did it:

```
function checkImages($id)
{
    global $mysqli; 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
        Img_1,
        Img_2,
        Img_3,
        Img_4,
        Img_5,
        Img_6,
        Img_7,
        Img_8,
        Img_9,
        Img_10,
        Img_11,
        Img_12,
        Img_13,
        Img_14,
        Img_15,
        Img_16,
        Img_17,
        Img_18,
        Img_19,
        Img_20,
        Img_21,
        Img_22,
        Img_23,
        Img_24,
        Img_25,
        Img_26,
        Img_27,
        Img_28,
        Img_29,
        Img_30
        FROM kittens
        WHERE
        id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($img1, $img2, $img3, $img4, $img5, $img6, $img7, $img8, $img9, $img10, $img11, $img12, $img13, $img14, $img15, $img16, $img17, $img18, $img19, $img20, $img21, $img22, $img23, $img24, $img25, $img26, $img27, $img28, $img29, $img30);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $row[] = array('Img_1' => $img1, 'Img_2' => $img2, 'Img_3' => $img3, 'Img_4' => $img4, 'Img_5' => $img5, 'Img_6' => $img6, 'Img_7' => $img7, 'Img_8' => $img8, 'Img_9' => $img9, 'Img_10' => $img10, 'Img_11' => $img11, 'Img_12' => $img12, 'Img_13' => $img13, 'Img_14' => $img14, 'Img_15' => $img15, 'Img_16' => $img16, 'Img_17' => $img17, 'Img_18' => $img18, 'Img_19' => $img19, 'Img_20' => $img20, 'Img_21' => $img21, 'Img_22' => $img22, 'Img_23' => $img23, 'Img_24' => $img24, 'Img_25' => $img25, 'Img_26' => $img26, 'Img_27' => $img27, 'Img_28' => $img28, 'Img_29' => $img29, 'Img_30' => $img30);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return ($row);
}
```

Then:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$kitties = checkImages($id);
if(is_array($kitties)){
    foreach($kitties as $row){
        $total = count(array_filter($row));
    }
}
```

I'll leave my old question so others can learn from my mistakes.

## Thank you @Alex.

I'm trying to return the number of rows that are not empty in a sql query. Every time I try, the result is always 1. I've tried to change up a few things but it still seems to be 1.

Edit: I want to count the number of queried rows that are not empty. The rows (Img_#) contain the path and filename of the images.

So for example, id 12 has 20 images stored. For each image stored, the location and filename is stored in one of the img_# fields. So when I query the table, I'd like to check how many of the 30 img_ fields are not empty.

Here's my first try:

```
function checkImages($id)
{
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT
        Img_1,
        Img_2,
        Img_3,
        Img_4,
        Img_5,
        Img_6,
        Img_7,
        Img_8,
        Img_9,
        Img_10,
        Img_11,
        Img_12,
        Img_13,
        Img_14,
        Img_15,
        Img_16,
        Img_17,
        Img_18,
        Img_19,
        Img_20,
        Img_21,
        Img_22,
        Img_23,
        Img_24,
        Img_25,
        Img_26,
        Img_27,
        Img_28,
        Img_29,
        Img_30
        FROM kitties
        WHERE
        id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);    
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_returns = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    if ($num_returns > 0)
    {
        return $num_returns;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

The second version:

```
function checkImages($id)
{
    global $mysqli; 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
        Img_1,
        Img_2,
        Img_3,
        Img_4,
        Img_5,
        Img_6,
        Img_7,
        Img_8,
        Img_9,
        Img_10,
        Img_11,
        Img_12,
        Img_13,
        Img_14,
        Img_15,
        Img_16,
        Img_17,
        Img_18,
        Img_19,
        Img_20,
        Img_21,
        Img_22,
        Img_23,
        Img_24,
        Img_25,
        Img_26,
        Img_27,
        Img_28,
        Img_29,
        Img_30
        FROM kitties
        WHERE
        id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($img1, $img2, $img3, $img4, $img5, $img6, $img7, $img8, $img9, $img10, $img11, $img12, $img13, $img14, $img15, $img16, $img17, $img18, $img19, $img20, $img21, $img22, $img23, $img24, $img25, $img26, $img27, $img28, $img29, $img30);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $row[] = array('Img_1' => $img1, 'Img_2' => $img2, 'Img_3' => $img3, 'Img_4' => $img4, 'Img_5' => $img5, 'Img_6' => $img6, 'Img_7' => $img7, 'Img_8' => $img8, 'Img_9' => $img9, 'Img_10' => $img10, 'Img_11' => $img11, 'Img_12' => $img12, 'Img_13' => $img13, 'Img_14' => $img14, 'Img_15' => $img15, 'Img_16' => $img16, 'Img_17' => $img17, 'Img_18' => $img18, 'Img_19' => $img19, 'Img_20' => $img20, 'Img_21' => $img21, 'Img_22' => $img22, 'Img_23' => $img23, 'Img_24' => $img24, 'Img_25' => $img25, 'Img_26' => $img26, 'Img_27' => $img27, 'Img_28' => $img28, 'Img_29' => $img29, 'Img_30' => $img30);
    }
    $num_returns = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    return ($num_returns);
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe because there is always only one row for specific ID? Are you sure you do not wrong rows with columns?

Comment: as you are selecting via id (primary key ?) it's normal behaviour to have only one result....

Comment: Are you sure you want to count rows, not "columns"? ;)

Comment: imo, stop using `num_rows` in queries. Just fetch the data and process it. You know you are going to process it anyway. So, assume you got it and process it. Keep a count of records processed and report a message if the count is zero.

Comment: use `COUNT()` against an IS NOT NULL or is not empty. Don't use num_rows for this.

Comment: imo, I want to start a 'Stop using 'num_rows' in PHP SELECT queries' campaign ;-/ It is one of the most useless things to be doing normally. I have seen it used when only one row will be returned anyway.

Comment: For those who are wondering why @RyanVincent thinks these (sensible) thoughts, here's a [link to an explanation](https://foundationphp.com/blog/2011/09/24/using-num_rows-with-a-mysqli-prepared-statement/).

Comment: @RyanVincent but I've only just learnt how to use Prepared Statements and now I can't use MySQLi_num_rows either!! I'm not sure you're right, as this is not what my lecturer teaches......   I need to complete this course for my lecturer in two days I can't learn all this new stuff,

Comment: First, use an SQL IDE (phpmyadmin is ) fine and run your select in that? does it return more than one row. To clarify, imo,  **never develop queries in PHP**. Always get them working in an SQL IDE ('mysql workbench' etc.) first. Now, you know everything works as you expect. Then you convert to PHP. If anything doesn't work then you know that you have not transcribed it correctly. i.e. **Converting  the query to PHP is the final step after you get it working correctly**

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the real answer**

It is not very clear what you are asking for since you did not provid neither table `boats` schema not `kitties` schema.

So my guess is : you have unique `id` index against both tables. That means when you query with `WHERE id = ?` mysql **MUST** return 1 row, because (as I mentioned) `id` is unique.

So what is your question? Do you have several records with same `id` in any of those tables? why do you use 2 different tables in your question?

Try to clarify what is your issue.

Comment: *The image rows contain the path and filename of the images.* there is no **image rows** there is fixed set of columns! Do you have any other table with images linked to `kitties` or `boats`? provide your db schema please?

Comment: I want to give you a +1 but because it's not a real answer you'll have to settle for a not real +1 for it. :-) . But yeah, your words are useful here :)

Comment: There is only one table (boats), I just named them to kitties because I thought it was funny. The table has well over 150 columns and I don't think most of it would be relevant to the question.

Comment: It does not explain what do you call **image rows** ?

Comment: Sorry about that, by image rows, I meant rows queried. I want to count the number of rows queried that are not empty

Comment: there is no empty rows returned by mysql NEVER. and it brings us back to the first question is your `id` column unique? or not? provide any proof that you have multiple records with same `id` please

Comment: There are no rows with the same id, it is unique. The id is the primary key and auto increments.

Comment: So that is the point I started from. This  YOUR query  **MUST, SHOULD, HAVE TO** return one row with `id` you asked in `WHERE` clause. Why do you expect any other value in `num_rows`?